# Pushing to an array while in a loop

Tags: arrays, perl, push, average

I am attempting to make a script that calculates the centroid of two amino acids then finds the distance between the two centroids. Obviously to do this I need all of the x,y,z coordinates which I have and can get at just fine. However, when I attempt to find the average of each of these I am simply getting the last value. Right now I have a fairly lengthy bit of code but the part that is giving me trouble is:

```
for (my $line = 1; $line <= $#data; ++$line) {
   if (($data[$line] =~ m/\s+$resid1\s+P/)&&($data[$line] =~ m/P\s+$resnum1\s+/)) {
    chomp $data[$line];
    my @splitline = (split /\s+/, $data[$line]);
    #print "$splitline[1] $splitline[3] $splitline[5] $splitline[6] $splitline[7] $splitline[8]\n";
            #atom#         #residue       #resid        #x-coor        #y-coor        #z-coor

    #calculate the average x coordinate
    my @xcoordinate_array;
    push @xcoordinate_array, $splitline[6];
    $xsum =sum(@xcoordinate_array);
    $xaverage=($xsum/$#xcoordinate_array);
    print "@xcoordinate_array \n";

    #calculate the average y coordinate
    my @ycoordinate_array;
    push @ycoordinate_array, $splitline[7];
    $ysum =sum(@ycoordinate_array);
    $yaverage =($xsum/$#ycoordinate_array);

    #calculate the average z coordinate
    my @zcoordinate_array;
    push @zcoordinate_array, $splitline[8];
    $zsum =sum(@zcoordinate_array);
    $zaverage=($zsum/$#zcoordinate_array);
    }

  }
```

Basically what this is supposed to do is search for some residue name (`resid1`), then some residue number (`resnum1`), read that line into an array (`@splitline`) (whose important contents are explained on line 5), then it is supposed to put each type of value into its individual array and use a subroutine (`sum`) to add the whole array and then divide by the number of things in the array.

However, when I print any of the averages it is only the last value. I understand why this is happening, however I cannot calculate the average outside of the loop since perl throws a fit saying that I cannot access the `@xcoordinate_array` outside of the loop. I understand that it is just overriding the array every time it goes the loop however I was hoping that it would add each value onto the array and at the end give the correct value.

So what I am asking is, how do I fix it so that I can get the array "full" with each value?

Comment: Declare the arrays outside of the loop?

Comment: I was doing that, and inside the loop... Its the little things that get you thanks.

Comment: Arrays start at zero too.

Answer (score 2):

You're re-creating the arrays, and calculating an average of a single element, for each matching line. Declare the arrays outside, and print their values after you're done with the file:

```
my (@xcoordinate_array, @ycoordinate_array, @zcoordinate_array);

for (my $line = 1; $line <= $#data; ++$line) {
   if (($data[$line] =~ m/\s+$resid1\s+P/) && ($data[$line] =~ m/P\s+$resnum1\s+/)) {
    chomp $data[$line];
    my @splitline = (split /\s+/, $data[$line]);

    push @xcoordinate_array, $splitline[6];
    push @ycoordinate_array, $splitline[7];
    push @zcoordinate_array, $splitline[8];
  }
}

#calculate the average x coordinate
if (@xcoordinate_array > 0) {
  $xsum     = sum(@xcoordinate_array);
  $xaverage = $xsum / @xcoordinate_array;
}

#calculate the average y coordinate
if (@ycoordinate_array > 0) {
  $ysum     = sum(@ycoordinate_array);
  $yaverage = $ysum / @ycoordinate_array;
}

#calculate the average z coordinate
if (@zcoordinate_array > 0) {
  $zsum     = sum(@zcoordinate_array);
  $zaverage = $zsum / @zcoordinate_array;
}
```

Comment: You'll also want to check the size of the arrays before performing the division so that you don't accidentally divide by zero. (Directed more towards the OP, but it would still be a good thing to include in the answer.)